# CursorAdapter with Alphabet-indexed Section Headers in android

Tags: android

I have to make own contact list, where i want to put section headers. In contact list i have to merge contacts (native contacts and some contacts comes from our server) [Here](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/) is an example of section header in list view. In that example all data will be read from database before showing the list. I don't want to read all data but read only data which will display in screen (8 to 9 rows), as list scroll read next data. Can we give the data to one by one row to the SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your own adapter which reads directly from the database in case its not in cache. This should be a good solution.

Comment: in example they use map for list of names from alphabet A, B,.. etc. If I read one by one row then I don't know that how many words starts from letter A. Give any example if you know.please help me.

Comment: get sorted data from the DB always